# Why does this PostGIS query take so long to run?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgis, postgresql-performance

I am new to PostGIS and SQL in general. I am running a query on polygons which, I hope, only selects distinct geometries and then repair (`ST_MakeValid()`) those distinct geometries. Thereby removing duplicate geometries in the process of fixing invalid geometries. However, the query takes really long to run (days). This is the SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table_geomfix AS 
SELECT gid,id, ST_MakeValid(geom) as geom 
FROM schema.table_polygons 
WHERE geom IN (SELECT DISTINCT geom FROM schema.table_polygons);
```

Running the two select statements separately is quick. About 1 minute for the `makevalid` and 15 seconds on the `distinct` statement.

1. Why does it take so long to run the combined statement?
2. Any advice for improving the query in order to make it faster?

NOTE: There is an index on the `geom` column.

Comment: It is slower because rather than just reading the (presumably already cached) data, it's having to write it. It's going to be an order of magnitude slower

Comment: Check the execution plan using `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: Btw: the `distinct` in the sub-query is useless and can be removed (but Erwin's query is even better)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is needlessly complicated and can be untangled to this 100 % equivalent one:

```
SELECT gid, id, ST_MakeValid(geom) AS geom
FROM   schema.table_polygons
WHERE  geom IS NOT NULL;
```

Neither original nor this one remove any duplicates (except by possibly removing some with `geom IS NULL`, but I doubt that was your intention).

#### Possible misunderstanding

There is a common misunderstanding concerning *output* column names in the `WHERE` clause - where you can *only* reference *input* column names. So, `geom` in:

```
WHERE geom IN ...
```

references the original input column *not* the output column (the result of `ST_MakeValid(geom)`).

Related:

- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119815/939860)

If your actual intention was to only keep rows where the result of `ST_MakeValid(geom)` is equal to any currently existing `geom` entry:

```
SELECT gid, id, ST_MakeValid(t.geom) AS geom 
FROM   schema.table_polygons t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   schema.table_polygons
   WHERE  geom = ST_MakeValid(t.geom)
   );
```

I added a table alias and table qualification to clarify what's what.

The index you mention is only going to help with this variant.

If your actual intention was to merge duplicate rows after fixing `geom` values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_MakeValid(t.geom))
       gid, id, ST_MakeValid(geom) AS geom 
FROM   schema.table_polygons t
ORDER  BY ST_MakeValid(t.geom), gid, id;
```

You did not define how to break ties and which row to keep from a set of dupes. I keep the row with the smallest `gid` from each set. And the smallest `id` from remaining dupes. Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

*Aside:* Calling a schema "schema" is like naming your son "son" and hoping for the best that no more sons shall arrive. In other words: don't.

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates, you have to be more specific about which rows to keep exactly.

Comment: That's why "Sean" Connery named his son "Jason" and not just "Son" ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, now that is what I call a proper answer. The last query does what I wanted and it takes about 50 seconds to run through about 3 000 000 records. I have much to learn. Thanks